# Bootstrap Carousel stacking images instead

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

The carousel does this
[On my page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVB3P.png) but I'm expecting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXdly.png)

(i know there is no actual image but that's because I don't have any placeholder image and its src is just "#")

this is the carousel part of the code:

```
<div class="container">
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <img src="#" alt="img1" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="#" alt="img2" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="item">
        <img src="#" alt="img3" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

and I have the CSS loaded at the top and all the js at the end of the page (first jquery, and then popper.js and last is the bootstrap)

Comment: What version of bootstrap are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to some of the class names you are using in the carousel, I assume you are using bootstrap 3. I tested your code with bootstrap 3 and it works. Since you did not indicate what version of bootstrap's cdn you are using I can only assume that might be the problem.

If you want to stay with the code you are using include the following in the `head` section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

**However**
I suggest you switch to the latest bootstrap (version 4). Then include the following in your `head` section:

```
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha256-46qynGAkLSFpVbEBog43gvNhfrOj+BmwXdxFgVK/Kvc=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

Include the follwoing where you want the carousel to appear. This is bootstrap 4's carousel:

```
  <h2>Carousel Example</h2>  
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" >
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="1.jpg" alt="img1" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="2.png" alt="img2" style="width:100%;">
      </div>

      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="3.jpg" alt="img3" style="width:100%;">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev" role="button">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next" role="button">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
  </div>
```

Then include the following just before the end of your body tag (i.e. `</body>`)

```
<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: ok, I think I have realized where the problem is... im using bootstrap 4.3.1 but the code for the carousel that I used is made for bootstrap 3, I haven't tested it yet, but i think that's the cause of my confusion for the past like 3 hours

Comment: This worked, I should've checked the versions before copying code from websites...